# Flutter 'List<Data>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

in flutter i should make this json structure for server side application:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "staff_id": "barcode1",
      "class_id": "session_id1",
      "class_name": "session_name1",
      "enter_date": "enter_date1",
      "Exit_date": "exit_date1",
      "username": "username1"
    },
    {
      "staff_id": "barcode2",
      "class_id": "session_id2",
      "class_name": "session_name2",
      "enter_date": "enter_date2",
      "Exit_date": "exit_date2",
      "username": "username2"
    }
  ]
}
```

## my code for implementing this structure:

```
class RestData{
  final List<Data> data;
  RestData({@required this.data});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'data':data
  };
}

class Data {
  final String staff_id;
  final String class_id;
  final String class_name;
  final String enter_date;
  final String exit_date;
  final String username;

  Data({this.staff_id,this.class_id,this.class_name,this.enter_date,this.exit_date,this.username});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : staff_id = json['staff_id'],
        class_id = json['class_id'],
        class_name = json['class_name'],
        enter_date = json['enter_date'],
        exit_date = json['exit_date'],
        username = json['username'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["staff_id"] = staff_id;
    map["class_id"] = class_id;
    map["class_name"] = class_name;
    map["enter_date"] = enter_date;
    map["exit_date"] = exit_date;
    map["username"] = username;

    return map;
  }
}

//--------------------------------------

List<Data> list = [];

for (int i = 0; i < barcodes.length; i++) {
  list.add(Data(staff_id: 'aaa', class_id: '1111', class_name: '2222', enter_date: '3333', exit_date: '444444', username: '5555'));
}
```

## result:

```
restData = {RestData} 
 data = {_GrowableList} size = 1
  0 = {Data} 
   staff_id = "aaa"
   class_id = "1111"
   class_name = "2222"
   enter_date = "3333"
   exit_date = "444444"
   username = "5555"
```

now! when i try to send this result to server i get this error:

```
List<Data> is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
```

my class to send data to server:

```
class SendInformation{
  Future<bool> sendDataToServer(List<Data> list) async{
    RestData restData = RestData(data: list);

    final response = await http.post('http://sample.com',body:restData.toJson()).timeout(Duration(seconds: 60));
    if(response.statusCode ==200){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure but i think problem is in this line of code:

```
restData.toJson()
```

## UPDATE TO JsonSerializable:

```
part 'rest_data.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class RestData {
  final List<Data> data;

  RestData(this.data);

  factory RestData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$RestDataFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$RestDataToJson(this);
}

part 'data.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Data {
  @JsonKey(name: 'staff_id')
  String staffId;
  @JsonKey(name: 'class_id')
  String classId;
  @JsonKey(name: 'class_name')
  String className;
  @JsonKey(name: 'enter_date')
  String enterDate;
  @JsonKey(name: 'exit_date')
  String exitDate;
  @JsonKey(name: 'username')
  String username;

  Data(this.staffId, this.classId, this.className, this.enterDate, this.exitDate, this.username);

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$DataFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$DataToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: I have one doubt here, what is the reason behind not implementing `RestData.fromJson` as you have implemented in `Data` class. And what is the reason of creating new map in toJson for `Data` class and not for `RestData` class?

Comment: @SharadPaghadal for `RestData.fromJson` i think for making this structure of json i need to have that.I'm not sure, my json structure has one object as `data` and array into that

Comment: you can use this way to parse json and create json https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries. This way all for toJson and fromJson method handled by it self, and this kind of error can not take place. Here you dont need to write toJson or fromJson method.

Comment: @SharadPaghadal not any change and i get current error too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class SendInformation{
  Future<bool> sendDataToServer(List<Data> list) async{
    RestData restData = RestData(data: list);

    final response = await http.post('http://sample.com',body:json.encode(restData.toJson())).timeout(Duration(seconds: 60));
    if(response.statusCode ==200){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Parse your json with `json.encode(Your_JSON_String)`